# "No public JRE" issue when invoke .jar from Python

Tags: java, python, python-2.7

For some reason it is necessary to run .jar from Python script. When I use construction like below,

```
cmd = 'java -jar ' + args
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I get an error:

```
No public JRE
```

I even get an error when try this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('java', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Well, google says public JRE - is a standalone JRE, not Java/jdkxxx/jre. And I have one. JDK_1.8.25 and JRE_1.8.25 are installed separetely. Of course, if I invoke that .jar file just from console (java -jar xxxx.jar) it is works.

Comment: What happens if you change cmd to point at where your java binary is? My hunch is this is probably a path issue, although I'd expect a different error to 'No public JRE'.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. It is works when I directly call c:\...\jre_1.8.25\bin\java.exe But why? PATH and JAVA_HOME variables are correct, because all the java applications work.

Comment: Most likely it's not inheriting the variables from your current command prompt shell. Under Windows I'd check that the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables are set system wide rather than just for the current user. It's been a while since I've done anything with subprocesses in Python, it should be fairly straightforward to grab the environmental variables though and use them (i.e. add the JAVA_HOME/bin dir to the java call) though.